# Is the spontaneous fission-yield curve for 240Pu known?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering, isotopes

I have not seen any data for the isotopes produced by spontaneous fission of plutonium. I believe this will be dominated by 240Pu as the major even-numbered isotope produced in reactor operations. I would guess it would be similar to the slow-neutron fission yield of 239Pu but it seems strange to me that this would not have been investigated. I can't think of a particular reason it would be classified.

Comment: Where have you looked?

Comment: I have primarily done journal searches, looked at the US Department of Energy Information Bridge, and the Hanford Site declassified documents. But I could have missed something.

Comment: try around nudat, amdc (https://www-nds.iaea.org/amdc/ ) or similar.

Comment: Also note the title of this paper :-D http://inspirehep.net/record/73054/

Comment: and  tables here too http://wwwndc.jaea.go.jp/cgi-bin/FPYfig?iso=nPu240  lot of info!